# Where are path aliases stored?

Tags: 8, database, path-aliases

I know that, in Drupal 7, path aliases are stored in the *url_alias* table. Which database table does Drupal 8 use to store path aliases?

Answer (score 2):

Prior to Drupal 8.8.0, they were stored in the same table as Drupal 7. From Drupal 8.8.0, path aliases are revisionable entities, whose primary database table  is *{path_alias}* and the revision table is *{path_alias_revision}*.